# Is there a way to configure email notification in GCP for Auto Updates on Google Managed Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to configure email notification in GCP for Auto Update notifications we received on Google Managed Services?

Example: SQL instances do frequently undergo scheduled maintenance at a specific window, will be prompted as a notification on the Console.

I have gone through a couple of documentation in GCP. Perhaps did not find relevant information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable notifications on CloudSQL scheduled/sudden maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969180/enable-notifications-on-cloudsql-scheduled-sudden-maintenance)