# Enable notifications on CloudSQL scheduled/sudden maintenance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-monitoring, google-alerts

I want to enable slack and email notifications for GCP CloudSQL instances's maintenance.

When i go to each one of CloudSQL instances, I can see notifications are `off` in maintenance settings.

However when i try to edit `maintenance` and `notification`  preferences, I am not able to find a way to turn on `notifications` for `maintenance`.

[image]

Also the docs are a bit misleading IMO.
On this Page https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/maintenance#notifications

There is a link for `You need to opt in to maintenance notifications.`  but it goes to a page where I couldn't find anything related to turning notifications on https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/set-maintenance-window#opt-in

My Questions :

- Can I enable all kind of `cloudsql` maintenance notifications including planned and sudden migrations.
- Is this possible to receive these notifications on slack and email.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only email is supported. You can do that by going to that url: https://console.cloud.google.com/user-preferences/cloud-profile

Then click on communication
[image]

From here you can activate the email communication by clicking on the slider.
[image: test]

You can select one or several projects in the dropdown list if you want.

---

**EDIT 1**

Sadly, you can't put a team email for notifications

[image]